# when I enter long text in ipBlock then it goes out from block in Impresspages, any solution?

Tags: block, slot, impresspages

When I enter long text in ipBlock or ipSlot (For Example sdfcvghbjnkmlsxdcfvghbjnkmldfctvgbyhujnbuihmklwedrftgyuhjnimkodcfvghbnjkml) then it goes out from ipBlock.

Any Solution?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with ImpressPages. This is controlled by your theme's styles.

There are two CSS properties to control this behavior:

1. word-break - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp
2. word-wrap - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp